# Any Ubiquitous Finance App That is on Mac, iOS and Windows?

Tags: macos

Is there any finance app that is on all three platforms (Or at least Mac and iOS?) that syncs well together? I am interested in budgeting and will need to keep track of my personal finances next year as well, so I need to find a system that works.

Answer (score 5):

[Mint.com](http://www.mint.com) is a web app with an iPhone (and Android) app.

Also, [You Need A Budget](http://www.youneedabudget.com) appears to support all three.

Answer (score 4):

As I have said before on this site, I personally use [Moneydance](http://moneydance.com/).

They have Mac, Linux and Windows support, and recently added an iOS mobile version that syncs with the desktop.

I have only used the Mac "desktop" version, and it seems to function well, but have not tried the other platforms, nor the iOS version.

I have no company affiliation, but am a (mostly) happy user.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SplashMoney](http://splashdata.com/splashmoney/). It works on many platforms, including iPhone, iPod and Mac, but also Palm OS, Android, Blackberry and windows.

I've been using it —since more than two years now— with my old Palm OS PDA and it works great. As I work mainly with Linux, I've tested very few times its synchronization with its desktop companion running on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using bearsofts money app, both in mac and iOS. I think only down side with this apps is you need to buy them separately.

http://ibearmoney.com/money-mac.html